# Simple hierarchical select control is not rendering

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

My more than an hour is wasted is trying to fix Simple hierarchical select module. I don't see controls on the entry screen of Content Type.

I have tested with taxonomies of one and two levels (with records of course). Browsed website in Chrome and IE. Created new Content Types, even whole new Drupal Website with new download of shs installed but no luck....

Any idea where I may be mistaken?

Comment: I think you can only use shs with field types of `Term Reference`.